Extreme points of a set of bounded increasing functions with a fixed integral.
I am interested in the extreme points of the set of functions :[0,1]→[0,1] such that (i)  is non-decreasing and (ii) $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = C$ for some $0<C<1$.
Without (ii), I can see that extreme points are indicator functions with the forms of $\mathbb{1}_{[t,1]}$ or $\mathbb{1}_{(t,1]}$.
With (ii), it seems like there are many possibilities. Are there any known results regarding this problem?

My guess would be that you get functions of the type $c 1_{[t,1]}$ and $c 1_{(t,1]}$ with $c (1-t) = C$. However, I did not check all the details.

"Extreme" in what sense?

@PaulSinclair In the sense that it cannot be expressed as a convex combination of two different points

@gerw Yes, they are, but I am afraid there are more. For example, $c1_{[0,t)}+1_{[t,1]}$ with $ct + 1-t = C$.
